# Generics type inference when cascaded calls of generic functions

Tags: go

While building a (my first) generics heavy library, and I'm bumping on some apparent limitations on the generics type checking implementation -- more likely my lack of knowledge.

Any ideas how to get something like below to work ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Number interface {
    int | float32
}

type MultiDimensionSlice interface {
    int | float32 | []int | []float32 | [][]int | [][]float32
}

func dimensions[S MultiDimensionSlice](s S) int {
    dims := 0
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        dims += 1
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    return dims
}

func indirection[T Number](v T) int {
    var slice2D [][]T
    return dimensions(slice2D)
}

func main() {
    x := [][]float32{{1}, {2}, {3}}
    fmt.Printf("x=%v, dims=%d\n", x, dimensions(x))
    fmt.Printf("indirection should return 2, got %d\n", indirection(0))
}
```

This fails to compile with the message `[][]T does not implement MultiDimensionSlice ([][]T missing in int | float32 | []int | []float32 | [][]int | [][]float32)`

But within the function `indirection()` all the allowed values of `T` will have an implementation in `dimensions()`.

Any help or pointers would be mostly appreciated!

([Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/LO1VqcOc9dG))

ps.: My problem is a bit more complex than that, but the issue is that one generic function (`indirection()` in this example) is not able to invoke the other (`dimensions()` here) because (apparently) Go compiler is not able to resolve the type parameter constraints (the information is there in compile time...).

Comment: Well, I think for compiler `[][](int | float32 )` and  `[][]int | [][]float32` are not the same

Comment: Yes, but even if I define:

`type MultiDimensionArray[T Number] interface { T | []T | [][]T }` it doesn't work for two reasons:

(1) Apparently I can't use `T` as one of those elements --not sure why.
(2) If I remove `T`, it kind of works, but it is not able to do automatic type inference, I have to define always both types, T and the multi-dimensional slice.  Thanks for the observation though! Ideally the compiler would figure that out, right ?

Comment: More on this topic, on this thread in golang-nuts@: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/abILUXiD8-k

Comment: Changing constraints will not make it work because of the same reason above. In short, we can say in go, type unions are not distributive. If you meet generics in other languages like me you need to adjust generics perspective according to go. I will provide an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments go has some restrictions in its generics perspective. You can achieve what you require with a workaround.

First, you need to change the interface you define. (Make it generic too)

```
type Number interface {
    int | float32
}

type MultiDimensionSlice[T Number] interface {
    Number | []T | [][]T
}
```

Then we need to change `dimension` methods type arguments. It would be much cleaner if go would let us define `dimensions` method like this

```
func  dimensions[S Number](s MultiDimensionSlice[S]) int {
```

But all we can do is :

```
func dimensions[S Number, K MultiDimensionSlice[S]](s K) int {
    dims := 0
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        dims += 1
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    return dims
}
```

And then we need to change how we call `dimensions` method. We need to provide an extra type argument in order to go can infer type argument `S`

```
func indirection[T Number](v T) int {
    var slice2D [][]T
    return dimensions[T](slice2D)
}

func main() {
    x := [][]float32{{1}, {2}, {3}}
    fmt.Printf("x=%v, dims=%d\n", x, dimensions[float32](x))
    fmt.Printf("indirection should return 2, got %d\n", indirection(0))
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tAqBudWa7Rs)

Comment: Thanks Eldar, this is great. I was trying something similar, but with a switched order of S and K type parameters, and then I had to pass them to each instantiation of dimensions() which was annoying. This is much better.  Still, something I'm missing is having Go to infer automatically the base type S -- it could afterall, the information is available in compile time (or there should be a away). Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: I have already a few generic functions like `dimension[]`, and I would hate to have at every function call to it, add this extra type parameter (that in principle it seems shouldn't be necessary)

Comment: @Jan That's why I called it ugly :). You have a point it would be better that go would infer that. But I think it is related to the interfaces you define are type lists.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm trying to create a math library that operates on Tensors (multi-dimensional arrays/slices) -- the underlying storage will actually be in C. I'm trying to provide a simple API to interact to/from Go native types (slices). By any chances would you have any suggestions on alternative interfaces or ways that would work in Go ? ... I can work around some of this by using reflection everywhere in the implementation, generics being just a thin API beautifying layer, but maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: @Jan I don't think I'm that expert on go. Maybe someone else could give more alternatives. But I can say there will always be trade-offs between design simplicity and implementation simplicity.